# Are suggested extensions computed locally or remotely?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed today that VSCode is recommending plugins to me based on what applications I have installed locally.

For instance, if I hover over the recommended Sublime Text Keymapper, it tells me it is recommending it because I have Sublime Text installed.

Does anyone know if the matching between my installed apps and available extensions is done locally, or if the list of known installed apps is sent to a server somewhere?

Comment: VSC fetches something, I am not sure if you also send installed apps, I would search for "telemetry" in the git repository to learn more. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/399f66e504d86f2c2d3e8918ee87d8074955f741/src/vs/workbench/parts/extensions/electron-browser/extensionTipsService.ts#L830-L860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's local. Here's the code for it: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/2b251d6e5ebefc2acdc6e73aae92ac2339b4984b/src/vs/workbench/parts/extensions/electron-browser/extensionTipsService.ts#L734

The non oss build just ships with a static mapping of executables names to extensions